# Internal server error: window is not defined error coming in my Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, window, ckeditor5

Hi please help me with this error which I am encountering in Angular project.

This is my server.ts code

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'; // Update to use the 'url' module
import path, { dirname, join, resolve } from 'path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Import 'domino' using TypeScript-friendly import
//import * as domino from 'domino';
//import domino from 'domino';
const fs = require('fs');
const compression = require('compression');
 'index.html')).toString();
//const win = domino.createWindow(template);
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist/examserver_frontEnd/browser', 'index.html')).toString();
const { window } = new JSDOM(template);
declare global {
interface Window {// Define properties here, if necessary}}
global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = window.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = window.Node;
global['Text'] = window.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = window.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = window.navigator;
global['MutationObserver'] = getMockMutationObserver();

// Assign 'window' and other properties to the global scope
// global.window = win;
// global.document = win.document;
// global.DOMTokenList = win.DOMTokenList;
// global.Node = win.Node;
// global.Text = win.Text;
// global.HTMLElement = win.HTMLElement;
// global.navigator = win.navigator;
// global.MutationObserver = getMockMutationObserver();
function getMockMutationObserver() {
  return class {
    observe(node: any, options: any) {
      // Implement the logic here
    }
    disconnect() {
      // Implement the logic here
    }
    takeRecords() {
      return [];
    }
  };
}
```

Rest of the code
[image]

[image]

I am getting error in AddQuestionComponent ts file here is the import
[image: Imports of AddQuestionComponent]

[image: My error image]

I tried using domino and also JSDOM to solve this problem but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [server-side rendering (ssr)](https://angular.io/guide/ssr). Which means all components get rendered on the server. However `window` is an object that only exists in the browser. So when you're rendering your component on the server it will throw an error saying that `window` is not defined.

I am not that familiar with Angular so I don't exactly know how to switch between CSR and SSR but perhaps that [this](https://blog.adnanebrahimi.com/how-to-switch-between-angular-ssr-or-csr-based-on-detecting-user-agent) could help you?

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer but I tried above solution and still getting the same error.
I am not that familier with Angular either.

Comment: @SwapnilKashish ah that's too bad... Sorry I can't be of much help then. Let's hope someone else has the answer

Answer (score 0):

Which angular version ? mb Ckeditor are not update for ssr ?

Comment: @angular-devkit/schematics  17.0.10
@angular/cdk  17.0.5
@angular/cli   17.0.10

"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.1", 
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^40.2.0",

Comment: a few ways to investigate: the compatibility of your node version with the ckeditor version, compatibility with ssr, look on the github repository for ckeditor, check dependencies needed for ckeditor, maybe ou are missing one. personally, I removed ckeditor from my project, too many compatibility problems

Comment: have you a issue ?

Comment: No I also removed ckeditor from the project and the error went away.